# The type InteractionCallback is not being found, and atom is removing the import statement

Tags: go

I am using the atom IDE, and for some reason whenever I add this to my imports:

"github.com/nlopes/slack"

And save the file, it removes the import.  So I'm not sure why but it isn't finding the InteractionCallback type in the library?

I copied this code from the [example](https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/8608e3c203889d74f3e98e41028145c4fdcfc8ea/dialog_test.go#L246):

```
func unmarshalSuggestionCallback(j string) (*InteractionCallback, error) {
    callback := &InteractionCallback{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &callback); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return callback, nil
}
```

I am getting this error:

> undefined: InteractionCallback

How can I tell if my library I just downloaded has the type defined?  Or am I referencing the type incorrectly?

Comment: Symbols from imported packages must be used slack.InteractionCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this command in your terminal:
    go get -u github.com/nlopes/slack

After that try to run this code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/nlopes/slack"
)

func unmarshalSuggestionCallback(j string) (*slack.InteractionCallback, error) {
    callback := &slack.InteractionCallback{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &callback); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return callback, nil
}

func main() {
    callback,_:=unmarshalSuggestionCallback(`{"type":"callback"}`)
    fmt.Println(callback.Type)
}
```

Everything should work fine, I have checked in my PC

Comment: strange, I used dep ensure -add to add the library to my vendor folder.  When I look in the vendor folder my dialog.go is missing code like this line https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/master/dialog.go#L52

Comment: dep by default pulls latest release of repository, not the master branch. https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/v0.4.0/dialog.go

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify from which package `InteractionCallback` comes from, in your case its slack package - `slack.InteractionCallback`

Comment: I prefixed it with slack, and added the import.  I get the same error ```undefined: slack.InteractionCallback```

Comment: Could you post self contained piece of code where you get this error?